# Do method outputs need to be bound to "self" in order to be used by other methods?

Tags: python, oop

I am very new to object-oriented programming in Python and I am working to implement the accepted answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37058/algorithm-to-find-out-points-of-inflection-for-a-polyline?noredirect=1&lq=1) in Python (it's originally in R).

I have a simple question - is it possible to access the output of one method for use in another method without first binding the output to `self`? I presume the answer is "no" - but I also imagine there is some technique that accomplishes the same task that I am not thinking of.

My start to the code is below. It works fine until you get to the `kappa` method. I would really like to be able to define `kappa` as a simple extension to `curvature` (since it's just the absolute value of the same) but I'm not particularly interested in adding it the list of attributes. I may just been overthinking this too, and either something like a closure is possible in Python or adding to the attribute list is the Pythonic thing to do?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

class Road(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y): #x, y are lists
        # Raw data
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        # Calculate and set cubic spline functions
        n = range(1, len(x)+1)
        fx = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(n, x, k=3)
        fy = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(n, y, k=3)
        self.fx = fx
        self.fy = fy

    def curvature(self, t):
        # Calculate and return the curvature
        xp = self.fx.derivative(); yp = self.fy.derivative()
        xpp = xp.derivative(); ypp = yp.derivative()
        vel = np.sqrt(xp(t)**2 + yp(t)**2)                  #Velocity
        curv = (xp(t)*ypp(t) - yp(t)*xpp(t)) / (vel**3)     #Signed curvature

        return curv

    def kappa(self, t):
        return abs(curv)
```

Comment: Should `kappa` take `t` as a parameter? Or is kappa the absolute value of curvature at some particular `t`?

Comment: @Robᵩ yes it should I will edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call the other method:

```
class Road(object):

    ...

    def kappa(self, t):
        return abs(self.curvature(t=t))
```

Comment: So simple and obvious (now that I know)! Thank you!